# Android - How to Expand Shortened Url using WebView

Tags: java, android, function, android-studio, android-webview

This is a function to get long url from short url such as goo.gl, bit.ly ...

```
private String expandUrl(String shortUrl) {
    String finalURL = "";
    webView.loadUrl(shortUrl);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            finalURL = webView.getUrl();
        }
    });
    return finalURL;
}
```

I want to store `webView.getUrl()` to a String call `finalURL` so that I can use it later, but it get error

> error: local variable finalURL is accessed from within inner class; needs to be declared final

what is my mistake?

Comment: I had edited the post just now, please take a look, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If finalURL variable is the member variable of the outer class, then it is possible for you to save the webView.getUrl() to finalURL for later purposes like parsing but if finalURL is a local variable, then its not possible unless you make it as an array object and final variable.
Use below code. instead of using plain finalURL, use finalURL[0] to store and parse later.

```
final String[] finalURL = {""};
String url1 = "goo.gl/RvoAZH";
webView.loadUrl(url1);
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
System.out.println(webView.getUrl()); // whatever way to debug
finalURL[0] = webView.getUrl();
}
});
```

Here in the below example you could see the value of local variable localVar being changed by the method(anonyMethod) inside the anonymous object from "" to a

```
public class Check {
    public void method() {
        final String[] localVar = {""};
        new Object() {
            public void anonyMethod() {
                System.out.println(localVar[0]); // sure
                localVar[0] = "a"; // nope
            }
        }.anonyMethod();
        System.out.println(localVar[0]);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Check ck = new Check();
        ck.method();
    }
}
```

Edit 1
Can you also post some more your code.

Edit 2
Added my own sample code.

Comment: any suggestion how to make it able to pass between difference class?

Comment: I have updated the answer above. Let me know if the above code works.

Comment: no error but the variable `finalURL[0]` has no value.

Comment: Its because maybe the function onPageFinished isn't called.

Comment: Make sure the function onPageFinished is called. I simulated the scenario in my local system. Create a function, anonymous object(new WebViewClient) and created a function inside the anonymous object which i called later and everything works fine.

Comment: I have added my code and try to run it. This should be the answer to your question since you are seeing no more error and it works perfectly for me. If you find my answer useful, please accept it and upvote

Answer (score 0):

You are using a already defined field in the anonymous class, if you need to alter this field then make it a class level variable. Declare it outside all your methods.
try this

```
public String finalURL = "";
```

Comment: I get error too, `error: cannot assign a value to final variable finalURL`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one

```
  private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            final Uri uri = Uri.parse(Uri.decode(url));
            return handleUri(uri);
        }

        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
            final Uri uri = request.getUrl();
            return handleUri(uri);
        }

        private boolean handleUri(final Uri uri) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onLoadResource(WebView view, String url) {
            if (url.equals("http://yoururl.com")) {
                // do something
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFormResubmission(WebView view, Message dontResend, Message resend) {
            resend.sendToTarget();
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
            mCacheWebView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            showSwipeRefresh();
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            if (webViewError) {
                setErrorWebView();
            } else {
                if (mCacheWebView != null) {
                    mCacheWebView.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { " +
                            "var head = document.getElementsByTagName('header')[0];"
                            + "head.parentNode.removeChild(head);" +
                            "})()");
                    mCacheWebView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            }
            hideSwipeRefresh();
        }

        @Override
        public void onReceivedHttpError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request, WebResourceResponse errorResponse) {
            super.onReceivedHttpError(view, request, errorResponse);
        }

        @Override
        public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {
            String message = "SSL Certificate error.";
            switch (error.getPrimaryError()) {
                case SslError.SSL_UNTRUSTED:
                    message = "The certificate authority is not trusted.";
                    break;
                case SslError.SSL_EXPIRED:
                    message = "The certificate has expired.";
                    break;
                case SslError.SSL_IDMISMATCH:
                    message = "The certificate Hostname mismatch.";
                    break;
                case SslError.SSL_NOTYETVALID:
                    message = "The certificate is not yet valid.";
                    break;
            }
            message += " Do you want to continue anyway?";
            Toast.makeText(mContext, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request, WebResourceError error) {
            onReceivedError(view, error.getErrorCode(), error.getDescription().toString(), request.getUrl().toString());
//            view.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/no_internet.html");
        }

        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
            webViewError = true;

        }
    }
```